# Read Google Spreadsheet cell value from external page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

in a Spreadsheet I have in cell A1 a number. I know how to read it and use in a html file created inside the script ( with HtmlService)

Is there a way to use the data in an external page?

On my site I'm  trying to have somethin like:

```
<p>In your bag there are</p> + "cellA1Value" + <p>carrots</p>
```

Ask if I have not been clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reading a value from an External Page

> You will have to put the appropriate value in Sheet1!A1.
>   You will have to deploy as webapp and give access to anyone, even anonymous.
>   Then everytime you load your page it loads that value into `<span id="spn1"></span>`

Here's the doGet():

```
function doGet(e){
  if(e.queryString !=='')
  {
    var s=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(e.parameter.range).getValue();
  }else{
    var s='No Query Parameter Received';
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(s);
}
```

Here's my external website code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
         $(function(){
            var url='https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxjlJNGYL65mItHLoL76jiEWX4iQlKzpywMAjg5SMgUUUZNbm8/exec?range=A1';
            $.get(url,function(data,status){
                document.getElementById('spn1').innerHTML=data;
            });
        });
            console.log('MyCode');
        </script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <div id="mydata">The size of my ruler is <span id="spn1"></span> inches.</div>
     </body> 
</html>
```

> You could use a multicell range and return a delimited string, split it and then loop through the array assigning values to different spans.

Comment: It works! one note: When I publish the script google gives me a link like "https://script.google.com/macros/u/0/s/HFkjkljfg eojwekkkjdXXXXXXxxxxxxxxttphWUYRk6HFIM1/exec" , to make it work in the HTML file we have to delete /u/0 from the link. I don't know why but it worked for me.

Comment: I tried to follow your suggest and return an array, but I receive errors... do you have any hint?

Comment: Actually I was thinking about editing that comment because I don’t think you can pass an away that way. But I do think you can pass a delimited string and then just split it on your own and get your array that way.

Comment: I think that the link that I was using is the first one that comes up when you deploy as web app and I believe it ends in exec